# Ocultar y mostrar controles en ASP.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy trabajando en ASP:NET C#. Tengo un imageButton oculto en mi MasterPage, para esto usé una clase definida en una hoja de estilos. En el modo de diseño veo que el control está oculto pero al cargar la página, el control aparece visible.
Lo que quiero hacer es que si el usuario no está logueado, no vea el botón y en caso de que sí esté logueado pueda verlo.
Ya probé con:

> ImageButton.visible = false;  // pero no funciona

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updMiImageButton" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
          <div class="cssMiImageButton" id="divMiImageButton">
              <asp:ImageButton ID="MiImageButton" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" CssClass="cssMiImageButton" Height="50px" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/miImagen_isologo.gif" Width="50px" OnClick="MiImageButton_Click" BorderStyle="None"/>
          </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Dejo el los código del aspx y del aspx.cs.
Lo que quiero es que cuando el usuario esté logueado vea el botón, para esto traté de setear la propiedad css del botón a visible desde el Page_Load pero tampoco me funcionó:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MiImageButton.Style["Visibility"] = "hidden";
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.usuarioLogin != null)
                {
                    this.ArmarMenu();
                    MiImageButton.Style["Visibility"] = "visible";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Site.Master:Page_Load", ex);
                this.lblMensaje.Text = msgErrorGenerico;
            }
        }

    }
```

**Actualización**
Corregí el código con la ayuda de @Thiago Loureiro. Ahora el botón no se ve cuando inicio la página pero alloguear al usuario el botón no se ve.
Dejo el código corregido, agregué "UpdateMode" al UpdatePanel y el updMiImageButton.Update();.
Dejo los códigos corregidos

Aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MiImageButton.Style["Visibility"] = "hidden";
        updMiImageButton.Update();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                if (this.usuarioLogin != null)
                {
                    this.ArmarMenu();
                    MiImageButton.Style["Visibility"] = "visible";
                    updMiImageButton.Update();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error("Site.Master:Page_Load", ex);
                this.lblMensaje.Text = msgErrorGenerico;
            }
        }

    }
```

Aspx:

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updMiImageButton" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
          <div class="cssMiImageButton" id="divMiImageButton">
              <asp:ImageButton ID="MiImageButton" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" CssClass="cssMiImageButton" Height="50px" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/miImagen_isologo.gif" Width="50px" OnClick="MiImageButton_Click" BorderStyle="None"/>
          </div>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo resolví quitando el updatePanel y el contentTemplate, dejando el botón solo adentro del div (por un tema de estilo y que encaje bien el página). Ahora funciona como lo necesito, dejo el código final.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        try
        {
            if (this.usuarioLogin != null)
            {
                this.ArmarMenu();
                MiImageButton.Style["Visibility"] = "visible";

            }
            else
            {
                MiImageButton.Style["Visibility"] = "hidden";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Site.Master:Page_Load", ex);
            this.lblMensaje.Text = msgErrorGenerico;
        }
    }

}
```

ASPX:

```
<div class="cssMiImageButton" id="divMiImageButton">
          <asp:ImageButton ID="MiImageButton" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" CssClass="cssMiImageButton" Height="50px" ImageUrl="~/Imagenes/miImagen_isologo.gif" Width="50px" OnClick="MiImageButton_Click" BorderStyle="None"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Después de cualquier comando tienes que disparar el updatepanel y realizar una actualización.
Por ejemplo

```
updMiImageButton.Update();
```

Compruebe también las opciones de UpdatePanel como los Triggers, usted puede colocar un evento de un botón como trigger para aquel updatePanel

Comment: Ahora sí funcionó y oculta el botón pero no logro mostrarlo nuevamente según si el usuario está logueado o no. Dejé la actualización del código.